# How Can I Export Over 50,000 Posts and Import ALL of Them in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

The Wordpress Export tool does not work with large numbers of posts. On top of that I have to add a plugin just to include images/attachments because I am only exporting a single category. It was bad enough that I had to export every 2 months worth of posts at a time just to stop Wordpress from freezing before the export file was made. Then I imported everything and found out that half (25,000 posts) were missing.

How can I export all of my posts with their images and import ALL of them.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess, its the server that is causing the issue, not WordPress. Generally, PHP has a time limit on how long scripts can run before they timeout. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Depending on your host, you can change/adjust but it would be better to loop through in batches to export.

One method would be a custom query to do that directly via MySQL.

Other would be a plugin that handles all of it.

I've used this one for importing/exporting 30-50k products at a time.
https://www.wpallimport.com/export/

This plugin is setup in the event that it does timeout, it doesn't lockup the site and just asks you to restart the process where it left off.

Answer (score -1):

You may try exporting the tables 'posts' and 'posts_meta' from the database and importing it into the new website's database. Also, for the images, copy the 'uploads' folder within the wp-content folder to the new website. Please make sure you take backups of database and uploads folder of the new website before doing this.

Comment: Wouldn't recommend this due to the fact IDs are generated automatically when creating posts and this could cause issues imported directly into a different site.